# IPFS upload is creating uselless subfile

Tags: javascript, ipfs

I am using Web3 Storage in order to upload my data to IPFS. The link always ends up being `ipfs://CID/1.png` instead of `ipfs://CID`.

This is my code:

```
import { Web3Storage, getFilesFromPath, CIDString } from 'web3.storage'

const files = await getFilesFromPath(`./outcome/1.png`)
const cid = await client?.put(files)
console.log(cid) //this returns only CID as it should, but the URL to access that data is different
```

Can I save the data under the CID without having to go to another file under it? What should be the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This slight change fixes it, more in [docs](https://web3.storage/docs/how-tos/store/#directory-wrapping).

```
import { Web3Storage, getFilesFromPath, CIDString } from 'web3.storage'

const files = await getFilesFromPath(`./outcome/1.png`)
const cid = await client?.put(files, {
        wrapWithDirectory: false
})
```